# How to get dropped rows when using drop_duplicates (Pandas DataFrame)?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, drop-duplicates

I use pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates() to drop duplicates of rows where all column values are identical, however for data quality analysis, I need to produce a DataFrame with the dropped duplicate rows. How can I identify which are the rows to be dropped? It occurs to me to compare the original DF versus the new one without duplicates and identify the unique indexes missing, but is there a better way to do this?

**Example**:

```
import pandas as pd

data =[[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C'],[1,'A'],[1,'A']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Numbers','Letters'])

df.drop_duplicates(keep='first',inplace=True) # This will drop rows 3 and 4

# Now how to create a dataframe with the duplicate records dropped only?
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Comment: Thanks Chris! This is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data =[[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C'],[1,'A'],[1,'A']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Numbers','Letters'])


df.drop_duplicates()
```

Output

```
    Numbers Letters
0   1       A
1   2       B
2   3       C
```

and

```
df.loc[df.duplicated()]
```

Output

```
    Numbers Letters
3   1       A
4   1       A
```